# Camera Permission in Andoid React Native

Tags: react-native, webview, expo

I have created an app using react native expo cli. The app is basically loading a website using webview. There is abutton to capture image. How to give permissions

Comment: Please add some more details.

Comment: Please use this documentation for expo: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/

Comment: Please use this documentation for expo: docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera this was not helpful

Comment: the app is just loading a website through web view. it has a option to capture image. when a button is clicked a pop shows file or camera option. if camera option is selected, nothing is happening. Have added "permissions": [ "CAMERA", "MANAGE_DOCUMENTS", "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_PHONE_STATE"], this also in app.json